# passing a multipolygon rather than the boundary box via a Crate DB table

Tags: python, shapely, geopandas, crate, cratedb

I have a geopandas dataframe called `geodf`. The geometry for each row in that dataframe is a multipolygon. For instance, if we consider the first row in the geometry column via the geodataframe:

```
bound = geodf['geometry'].iloc[0]
print(bound)
```

it looks something like this:

```
MULTIPOLYGON (((-86.46228799973933 34.31021100007911, -86.46447100007661 34.31018399970606, -86.46447800010341 34.31197299998977, -86.4623920000716 34.31198799958079
```

The multipolygon itself is massive so I tried to create a box for it instead

```
box = shapely.geometry.box(*geodf.bounds)
```

and then I passed `box` through the following query via our Crate DB server:

```
query = """
                 SELECT geohash, grid,shape 
                 FROM geo 
                 WHERE layer = 'pop' 
                AND MATCH(shape, '{}') USING within;
          """.format(box)
geoCursor.execute(query)
results = geoCursor.fetchall()
District = gpd.GeoDataFrame(results, columns = ['geohash', 'grid','shape'])
```

where I pass the polygon`box` in the query above via `.format(box)`

What I would like to do instead is pass `bound` instead of `box` in the query above(note that the query above works for `box`). However, when I try to pass `bound` I get the following error:

`ProgrammingError: SQLActionException[UnhandledServerException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert Map "{type=MultiPolygon, coordinates=[[[[D@2b59d486}" to shape]`

I wasn't able to diagnose error above. I was wondering why `bounds` does not work and how I could might make it work? We don't want to use a boundary box because there's a lot of excess area that is not contained in our multipolygon boundary

Answer (score 0):

You could represent the multipolygon as dict that resembles the geoJSON format
and then use parameter substitution. I'm not familiar with shapely, so I can't comment on how you get the dict representation, but with a manually crafted dictionary it would look as follows:

```
multipolygon = {
    "type": "MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates": [
        [
            [
                [ 40.0, 40.0 ],
                [ 20.0, 45.0 ],
                [ 45.0, 30.0 ],
                [ 40.0, 40.0 ]
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                [ 20.0, 35.0 ],
                [ 10.0, 30.0 ],
                [ 10.0, 10.0 ],
                [ 30.0, 5.0 ],
                [ 45.0, 20.0 ],
                [ 20.0, 35.0 ]
            ],
            [
                [ 30.0, 20.0 ],
                [ 20.0, 15.0 ],
                [ 20.0, 25.0 ],
                [ 30.0, 20.0 ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
}

c.execute('select * from t where match(x, ?) using within', (multipolygon, ))
print(c.fetchall())
```